# how do I create packages that generate messages for all other packages

Tags: ros, genmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're maintaining our custom made ros client library (http://wiki.ros.org/roseus). We'd like to create new package that holds all messages files that compiled into `eus` language, so that uses do not need to generate on their local machine. How do I create such a packages or how do I tell ros build firm to do that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152491/how-do-i-create-packages-that-generate-messages-for-all-other-packages./) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2014-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably a bad idea, because there's no way to query for "all messages" in the ROS ecosystem, and users who have unreleased messages will still have to do their own message generation.

The two current approaches I've seen that work well are:

- roscpp/rospy/roslisp approach: the rospy, roscpp and roslisp message generators are very lightweight, and are incorporated into the core message_generation package, so roscpp, rospy and roslisp messages are generated as part of the default message generation. If your message generation is simple and lightweight, you could petition to get it included here.
- rosjava approach: rosjava is packaged and distributed separately through a maven repository (pretty standard for Java packages). Their build system generates a jar (package) for each message package, and they distribute compiled versions of the core messages. If a user is using core messages, the Java build system grabs them from the repository, otherwise they're built locally.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-04-13**:
The *rosjava* approach has the disadvantage that it can never be "promoted" to become a language being support by default (by adding it to message_generation) in the way it is currently done. Therefore I recommend you to write a "geneus" (?) package similar to the existing generators: gencpp, genpy, genlisp.

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2014-04-14**:
Thanks for answer and comment.